# Logwatch: 3 Major DNS Issues - Are These Fixes Correct?

Tags: domain-name-system

Can anyone take a look at these DNS issue and tell me if any of them are critical and could result in DNS issue (500 errors) and if the fixes that I found online are correct.

## 1. Max Open Files

```
 max open files (1024) is smaller than max sockets (4096): 2 Time(s)
```

**Fix according to Google:**

> 1. Open your named.conf and add the following line to the Options
>      section:
>
>    files 4096;
> 2. Open /etc/security/limits.conf and add the following line:
>
>    named   soft   nofile   4096

## 2. Network unreachable

```
network unreachable resolving '137.7.24.188.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN': 2001:610:240:0:53::193#53: 1 Time(s)
```

**Fix according to Google:**

> To fix this you have to start the bind damon with "-4" (IPv4 only).
>   You can add the line "OPTIONS="-4"" to /etc/sysconfig/named to do so.

## 3. the working directory is not writable

```
the working directory is not writable: 2 Time(s)
```

**Fix according to Google:**

> $ sudo chmod g+w named

## OTHER ISSUES:

```
using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]: 2 Time(s)
using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]: 2 Time(s)
client 83.140.19.133 view external: zone transfer 'domain/AXFR/IN' denied: 2 Time(s)
```

Any help, much appreciated. I already upgraded my kernel via yum, but I am not sure if this will help

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: "500 errors"?  You are aware that DNS isn't HTTP, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two could definitely cause intermittent problems; the third should bomb your server fairly completely.  All three should be fixed.

Comment: It's not like the server is writing to /var/named all the time, only when the zones are changed, am I right? If so, then it would not "bomb" the server - what are you referring to?

Comment: I also found out that this only happens when BIND restarts, so the "not resolving" is probably related to that. And the working directory error is a common bug with WHM http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/named-working-directory-not-writable-154449.html